# Index like sql order

Tags: sql

I have a column with a string value, something like `1, 1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2, 2, 2.1, 1.3, 1.1.3`, one for record, of course, and i want a sentence that returns the records ordered by this field, like a book index

```
1
1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3
1.2
1.3
2
2.1
```

Thanks

Comment: just use `Order by` no ?

Comment: Do any values ever get above 9?  If not then a straight string comparison would work.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO #tab(col)
SELECT '1'
UNION ALL SELECT '1.1'
UNION ALL SELECT '1.1.2'
UNION ALL SELECT '1.1.3'
UNION ALL SELECT '1.2'
UNION ALL SELECT '1.3'
UNION ALL SELECT '2'
UNION ALL SELECT '2.1';

SELECT *
FROM #tab
ORDER BY col;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393274)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

Just for fun and experiment solution for **SQL Server 2012+**:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT col,
  CASE LEN(col) - LEN(REPLACE(col, '.', ''))   
     WHEN 0 THEN  col + '.0.0.0'
     WHEN 1 THEN  col + '.0.0'
     WHEN 2 THEN  col + '.0'
     ELSE col
  END AS col_alt
  FROM #tab
)
SELECT col
FROM cte
ORDER BY 
  LEN(PARSENAME(col_alt,4)),
  PARSENAME(col_alt,4),
  LEN(PARSENAME(col_alt,3)),
  PARSENAME(col_alt,3),
  LEN(PARSENAME(col_alt,2)),
  PARSENAME(col_alt,2),
  LEN(PARSENAME(col_alt,1)),
  PARSENAME(col_alt,1);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393287)**</kbd>

Comment: No limits, indexes can have any deep and any integer value

Answer (score 1):

If the values between the dots are all single characters (as in the question), then the easiest way is to order by the length of the string and then the string:

```
order by len(col), col
```

(In some databases, `len` might be spelled `length`.)

Note:  this only works when single digits separate the dots.  A more general solution requires some knowledge of the database.